# Sum not recognized as a linear operator by Solve

Tags: equation-solving, summation

When I try to solve an equation with a constant under the summation sign, Mathematica does not factor the constant out of the summation and fails to solve a simple equation.

How do I make Mathematica handle the problem that arises below as it handles the second case that follows it:

```
z[t_] = Sum[2 a[0] + m[t], {t, 0, M}]; 
Solve[z[t] == 0, a[0]]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
>
> ```
> Solve[Sum[2*a[0] + m[t], {t, 0, M}] == 0, a[0]]
> ```

```
z[t_] = a[0] Sum[2, {t, 0, M}] + Sum[m[t], {t, 0, M}];
Solve[z[t] == 0, a[0]]
```

> ```
> {{a[0] -> -(Sum[m[t], {t, 0, M}]/(2 (1 + M)))}}
> ```

Comment: Maybe: `z[t_] = Sum[#, {t, 0, M}] & /@ (2*a[0] + m[t]); Solve[z[t] == 0, a[0]]`?

Answer (score 5):

One idea is to create a function that expands out sums:

```
expandSums[expr_] := expr /. s_Sum :> RuleCondition[expandSum[s]]

expandSum @ Sum[a_, i__] := factorSum[Expand[a], i]

factorSum[a_Plus, i__] := Thread[Unevaluated @ factorSum[a, i], Plus]
factorSum[a_Times, i__List] := With[{iter = Alternatives[i][[All, 1]]},
    Times[
        DeleteCases[a, _?(Not @* FreeQ[iter])],
        Sum[DeleteCases[a, _?(FreeQ[iter])], i]
    ]
]
factorSum[a_, i__] := Sum[a, i]
```

Then you can apply this function to your [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum):

```
expanded = expandSums[Sum[2 a[0] + m[t], {t, 0, M}]];
expanded //TeXForm
```

> $2 a(0) \sum _{t=0}^M 1+\sum _{t=0}^M m(t)$

and then use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Solve[expanded == 0, a[0]] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{a(0)\to -\frac{\sum _{t=0}^M m(t)}{2 \sum _{t=0}^M 1}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: I do not understand this code yet, but this is robust. I could find p[0] after the change: expanded = 
  expandSums[
   Sum[2 (p[0] m[t] + 2 v[t] p[0] p[1] + p[1] m[t])^2, {t, 0, M}]];

Comment: Thanks for your kind response @CarlWoll. After simplification, the sum of "one's",  ∑1 from 0 to M, in your response evaluates to equal (1+M). This simplification does not occur when expecting ∑∑m[t] to equal (1+M)* ∑m[t]. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica works this way. Notice that the summation with explicit numeric bounds:

```
Sum[2 + x[n], {n, 3}] == 6 + x[1] + x[2] + x[3]
```

returns result `True`. The summation with no explicit numeric bounds:

```
Sum[2 + x[n], {n, k}]
```

returns the unevaluated result. There are good reasons why it works this way. However, there are always more than one way to get the results you want and you have used one of them yourself. Unless I am very mistaken, there is no easy way here working only within `Sum[]`.

Another way is to treat summation as a linear operator with the help of `Map[]`. The following code attempt:

```
Map[Sum[#, {t, 0, N}] &, (2 a[0] + m[t])]
```

does just that. The idea is that `Map[]` works on the top level of the sum `2 a[0] + m[t]` and *distributes* the `Sum[]` over the top level `Plus[]`.
Of course, this is risky code because it will blindly do similar things if you apply it to `2 a[0] * m[t]` and, of course, `Sum[]` **doesn't** distribute over `Times[]`.

An improved and safer version of it is this code:

```
(2 a[0]+m[t]) /. x : __Plus :> Map[Sum[#, {t, 0, N}] &, x]
```

which **only** distributes over a sum of terms because of the explicit `Rule[]`. It probably does what you want.