Verify simple equality involving integral
Can anyone kindly explain why Mathematica does not say that these two equations are the same? I have just removed two terms which multiply to one:

FullSimplify[
  ((1 + E^(t*λ2))*x0*λ1 - (1 + E^(t*λ1))*x0*λ2 + (-E^(t*λ1) + E^(t*λ2))*Π0 + (λ1 - λ2) *
    Integrate[(((1 + E^((t - u)*λ2))*λ1 - (1 + E^((t - u)*λ1))*λ2)*(-r + i[u]))/(λ1 - λ2), {u, 0, t}])/(λ1 - λ2) == 
  ((1 + E^(t*λ2))*x0*λ1 - (1 + E^(t*λ1))*x0*λ2 + (-E^(t*λ1) + E^(t*λ2))*Π0 +
    Integrate[((1 + E^((t - u)*λ2))*λ1 - (1 + E^((t - u)*λ1))*λ2)*(-r + i[u]),
  {u, 0, t}])/(λ1 - λ2)]
]



As to code formatting, check this: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871 2. Currently none of those functions for arithmetic simplification can handle unevaluated Integrate, Sum, etc. AFAIK. We need a bit extra coding


Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198193/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38166/1871 There should be more.

I am guessing that part of the reason MMA can't tell you the result is just True is that it is VERY careful about things like integrals and denominators possibly being zero or infinity. If I slightly change your input to be Simplify[...your input...,λ1-λ2!=0] Note that Simplify[expr,hint] tells Simplify to use that hint when simplifying. So what I did was tell it that the denominator wasn't zero. Output shows it realized it could multiply to get rid of one denominator. It didn't pull the denominator out of your integral, it might be infinite. Are there any other hints you are ASSUMING?

Simplify[(((1+E^(t λ2))x0 λ1)-(1+E^(t λ1))x0 λ2+(-E^(t λ1)+E^(t λ2))Pi0+(λ1-λ2)* Integrate[(((1+E^((t-u)*λ2))*λ1-(1+E^((t-u)*λ1))*λ2)*(-r+i[u]))/(λ1-λ2),{u,0,t}])/(λ1-λ2)== (((1+E^(t λ2))x0 λ1)-(1+E^(t λ1))x0 λ2+(-E^(t λ1)+E^(t λ2))Pi0+Integrate[((1+E^((t-u)*λ2))*λ1-(1+E^((t-u)*λ1))*λ2)*(-r+i[u]),{u,0,t}])/(λ1-λ2),λ1-λ2!=0] Check this carefully to try to make certain I didn't make any mistakes. Thanks

@Bill I know it's also not equal to infinity. I have tried your suggestions, specifying that λ1-λ2!=0 and λ1-λ2!=infinity and it still doesn't work. Did you say it worked for you?

@xzczd I followed those exact steps. I generated the code in Raw input format but when I paste it, it becomes like this.

Didn't work for me. Not enough for you to know it is not infinity. Question is: does MMA know it is not infinity. Worse, MMA usually tends to assume all variables can be complex numbers, unless you give hints saying this is not true. The real task is to figure out exactly what you need to tell MMA so that it will carry out the steps that you want it to do. Little experiments giving it various hints and seeing if those hints get closer to what you want are good. If you read the docs for Integrate, look at "details and Options" you can find optional Assumptions to give it hints

Have you tried the Ctrl+Shift+I approach?
